# Phonegap - I cannot save video file to device documents folder

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have been developing an application using phonegap and build with phonegap. But I cannot save the captured video file in the app documents folder in iphone since I am getting a different path for video as compared to image. For the images, the functionality works fine. But for video I am using captureVideo method of phonegap capture API and in its callback, it returns a different path which cannot be resolved to a file entry.

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(videoCaptureSuccess, videoCaptureError, {limit:1}); 

function videoCaptureSuccess(fileURL) { 
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURL, function(fileEntry) { 
  // doing something
}); 
}
```

resolveLocalFileSystemURI not working as the path is something like `'/private/var/mobile/...'`. But for image it is `'/var/mobile/...'`

Please help me to save the captured video to the app documents

Thanks in advance